# How can I add a Let Ring keyboard shortcut for TuxGuitar?

Tags: tuxguitar

In the latest version of TuxGuitar (1.4), there's an option under Beat -> Effects for "Let Ring". However, this has to tediously be done for each note through the menu interface.

Under Tools -> Shortcuts, there is no option to configure a shortcut for "Let Ring".

How can I add this keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TuxGuitar shortcut configurations are stored in an XML file. I was able to add my own shortcut for the "Let Ring" feature by guessing its name based on other configuration entries in this file. The steps are:

1. Open `~/.tuxguitar-1.4/config/shortcuts.xml`
2. Add this entry (which sets "r" as the key): `<shortcut action="action.note.effect.change-let-ring" keys="r"/>`
3. Save the file, close and relaunch TuxGuitar
4. When you cycle through notes with the arrow keys, you can now hit "r" to mark each note as "Let Ring"

Comment: Great answer! On my (Windows) machine and tux1.5.4, the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\tuxguitar-1.5.4\dist`.

Comment: I tried to apply this in windows, but it seems like TG isn't even using the file. When I change shortcuts in the application, it doesn't save them to the shortcuts file